# iPhone HelpViewController undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I have a strange XCode project compilation issue. I have a subclass of `UIViewController` called `HelpViewController` that is created the same way as several other similar classes I have for adding to a `UITabBarController`.

When compiling I get the error; `HelpViewController undeclared (first use in this function)` when I try and create an instance to add to the tab bar.

If I rename the class to `GuideViewController` (*.h, *.m, *.xib filenames; all occurances in .h and .m; `#import "*.h"` and `* alloc`) the compilation succeeds but if I rename it back to `HelpViewController` it fails again with the same error.

I looked for `HelpViewController` in the dev docs but couldn't find anything to suggest it is a reserved name. Why might this particular class name be causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'd got my XCode project in a mess. When I deleted my *ViewController class at some point I had selected to only delete the references and not move the files to the trash as well. This removed the reference for the File Owner's outlet for view which could be seen as a warning in Interface Builder. The lack of a correct view reference prevented the ViewController being used (A View Controller is also a View). Since the files were still present in the file system (but not shown in the XCode project) they compiled badly. I deleted the files and selected to move them to the trash and then recreated them from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like a #import is missing or incorrect. But it looks like you've covered that. Make sure you do a clean of the project (or delete the build directory), it could be old artifacts getting in the way.

Comment: Exactly what I thought as I had that error on the other view controllers and adding the #import fixed those. Thought I had a typo but all the syntax highlighting is showing correctly and the #import file pre-populates so it finds the header file OK. Just did a full clean and then changed back to Help* then cleaned again and still get the same build error. For now I'll just use a different name but it doesn't help my OCD to not get the name I want.